# If I would have had to be leaving the city tomorrow, would you come see me today for the last time?

Tags: grammaticality, conditional-constructions

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

- If I **would have had to be leaving** the city tomorrow, would you come see me today for the last time?

I wanted to say that *If I were to have been forced to leave the city tomorrow would you come visit my place today to see me for the last time?*

Somehow the "**would have had to be leaving**" bothers me. I feel that I should write:

- If I **would have to leave** the city tomorrow, would you come see me today for the last time?
- If I **would have to be leaving** the city tomorrow, would you come see me today for the last time?
- If I **had to be leaving** the city tomorrow, would you come see me today for the last time?
- If I **had to leave** the city tomorrow, would you come see me today for the last time?

Comment: Some US (AmE) speakers (but *very* few BrE speakers) would be happy enough to fully enunciate the first ***would*** in your example, but in practice it would would normally be reduced to *If **I'd've** had to be leaving* - or more likely, just *...had to leave*. Note that ***had*** in such contexts would normally be enunciated as ***hat*** by most native speakers. And I must just point out that I'm one of many people who'd be quite happy to "expand" that *If I'd've had to do it* to *If I **had have had** to do it.* I don't care if that bothers pedantic grammarians.

Answer (score 1):

You are right

> If I **would have had to be leaving**

sounds strange, better might be

> If I **would be leaving** tomorrow, would you come see me?
>
> If I **would have to leave** tomorrow, would you come see me?
>   If I **had to leave** tomorrow, would you come see me?

are better choices for asking in the *present* about something in the *future*

> If I **would have left** last Monday, would you have come see me?

would be used for asking in the *present* about something in the *past*

Comment: `If I had.., I would have...` - that's the sentence structure in my grammar book. Is it possible to have `If I would have...` as a part of a proper sentence (it and will/would on the same side)?